# Append code having multiple single multi quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to append the codes below on `body` but when I am doing this `onReady`, I am getting this error:

> unterminated string literal

Below in code that I have appended:

```
jQuery('body').append('
    <!--
        Start of DoubleClick Floodlight Tag: Please do not remove
        This tag must be placed between the <body> and </body> tags, as close as possible to the opening tag.
        Creation Date: 10/12/2015
    -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var axel = Math.random() + "";
        var a = axel * 10000000000000;
        document.write(\'<iframe src="https://338333293.fls.doubleclick.net/activityi\' + a + \'?" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" style="display:none"></iframe>');
        </script>
        <noscript>
        <iframe src="https://333383293.fls.doubleclick.net/activityi;src=3383293;?" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" style="display:none"></iframe>
        </noscript>
    <!-- End of DoubleClick  -->
');
```

I have done accroding to this [StackOverflow Suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955208/jquery-escaping-quotes-issue-when-prepending-content)

But this is not working for me

Comment: i think your html is breaking. Please check with alert();

Comment: You should create fiddle for this so any one can help you with html break.

Comment: Shouldn't `</iframe>');` be `</iframe>\');`

Comment: Are the newlines in your code as well, or added here for clarity? Because they shouldn't be in your code.

Comment: @Rajesh i have done that but it is not working

Comment: @Gaurav can you check if all quotes (single/double) are added properly. Take reference from *void's* answer and create a string and add this variable to body instead of writing string inline. Exactly what *Parth* has done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be

```
//Create Html with proper concatenation 
var html='<!--Start of DoubleClick Floodlight Tag: Please do not remove This tag must be placed between the <body> and </body> tags, as close as possible to the opening tag. Creation Date: 10/12/2015-->';
html+='<script type="text/javascript">';
html+='                    var axel = Math.random() + "";';
html+='var a = axel * 10000000000000;';
html+='document.write(\'<iframe src="https://338333293.fls.doubleclick.net/activityi\' + a + \'?" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" style="display:none"></iframe>\');';
html+='</script>';
html+='<noscript>';
html+='<iframe src="https://333383293.fls.doubleclick.net/activityi;src=3383293;?" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" style="display:none"></iframe>';
html+='</noscript>';
html+='<!-- End of DoubleClick  -->';

//append html to dom
jQuery('body').append(html);
```

Comment: @Gaurav have you checked?

Comment: @Gaurav peoblem with `<script>`  tag comment out that.

Comment: you can load this html from another file so their can not be break perform. $("div").load("s1.html");

Answer (score 1):

For this ther are multiple ways:

**First:**

```
"Hello World"
+"Yo it's amazing"
+'Yes I "Love" it';
```

**Second:** Use ``` `` ``` (template)

`Hello World
Yo it's amazing
Yes I "Love" it`

Answer (score 0):

You had missed `\` after `</iframe>`
 use this and see

```
<script>
 jQuery('body').append('
                <!--
                Start of DoubleClick Floodlight Tag: Please do not remove
                This tag must be placed between the <body> and </body> tags, as close as possible to the opening tag.
                Creation Date: 10/12/2015
                -->
                <script type="text/javascript">
                var axel = Math.random() + "";
                var a = axel * 10000000000000;
                document.write(\'<iframe src="https://338333293.fls.doubleclick.net/activityi\' + a + \'?" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" style="display:none"></iframe>\');
                </script>
                <noscript>
                <iframe src="https://333383293.fls.doubleclick.net/activityi;src=3383293;?" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" style="display:none"></iframe>
                </noscript>
               <!-- End of DoubleClick  -->');
</script>
```